# Would a nit-picking grammarian object to "Probably best you don't know"?

Tags: tenses

From *Boston Legal* (or your everyday conversation):

> "He and I will be going on a little vacation."
>
> "Where?"
>
> "Probably best you don't know."

Being short for "It would probably be best if you didn't know," the spoken version changes the past tense to the present in the second half of the sentence.

Is this something a grammarian would find fault with? Or dismiss it as colloquial?

Comment: The long form could also use the present tense in the if-clause: "_It would probably be best if you don't know._" So I don't imagine that grammarians would find fault with the shortened version.

Comment: @Shoe: I beg to differ. I mean, shouldn't the presence of "would" automatically suggest the past tense?

Comment: "Would" in the main clause combined with past tense in the if-clause produces what is often called a second conditional. This is certainly a common pattern. But it is not a rule to be followed on all occasions. In conversational English it is natural and grammatical to mix up the tenses in the two clauses.

Comment: I'm not a grammarian, but I'd nit pick over the spelling of your title. :p

Comment: "*A* grammarian", surely, but, to prevent closure based on matter of opinion, you might want to rephrase it to "is this sentence grammatical?" or something of the sort.

Comment: You're not nitpicking the absence of a subject and main verb?

Comment: @Joachim: "Grammatically correct," you mean.

Comment: @StuartF: That's omission. Not the same thing.

Comment: @ralph.m: I stand corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @Ricky grammatical: "conforming to the rules of grammar". Says Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @joachim: I'm a staunch believer in the Second Commandment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitpicking grammarians don’t tend to correct speech; in fact they probably talk just like you do. And if they don’t now, they will when the subjunctive altogether slips away from the language.

But since you asked . . .

Let’s say that *it’s* is elided in front of *best*. The expression *it’s best*, like *it’s essential* and *it’s important*, is followed by *that* (not *if*), and it triggers the “present” subjunctive (which uses the bare infinitive). Here the grammatical person is changed so you can better see it:

> *It’s essential [that] I be on time.* (Not **It’s essential if I be on time.*)
> *It’s essential [that] I not be late.* (Not **It’s essential [that] I do not be late.*)
> *It’s best [that] he know.* (Not **It’s best if he know.*)
> *It’s best [that] he not know.* (Not **It’s best [that] he do not know.*)

So: *Best you not know.* (Not **Best you don’t know.*)

Let’s say that *it would be* is elided in front of *best*. Now we have an “unrealized” conditional (followed by *if* — not *that*), and it triggers the “past” subjunctive (which uses the past tense except with *be* in the first and third person singular):

> *It would be best if you didn’t know.* (Not **It would be best if you
> don’t know.*)
>  *It would be best if he were unaware.* (Not **It would
> be best if he was unaware.*)

So: *Best you didn’t know.* (Not **Best you don’t know.*)

Let’s say that *it will be* is elided in front of *best*. Now everything seems to be business as usual:

> *It will be best if you don’t know.*

So: ***Best you don’t know.***

Comment: I knew I could count on you.

Answer (score 4):

No, a nitpicking grammarian would have no grounds to assume that the phrase did not stand for:

- It **is** probably best you **don't** know.

Which is why we are quite likely to find reduced sentences such as:

- Probably best **that** you don't know.

There are no nits here to be picked.

Comment: What's *don't* for here? Isn't it just best you not know?

Comment: @tchrist Depends on whether you want a tensed clause or a subjunctive one as the complement of *know*. Both are possible. Subjunctive clause more common in US English and tensed one in UK -  but both occur in both varieties.

Comment: @tchrist Oops I should have said “as the extraposed subject of  *be best* not the complement of *know*. Apologies.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Interesting! It might be worth noting that the missing "It is" is a case of conversational deletion.